# Where I can complain about an unfair account suspension?

Tags: support, account-suspension

My account on sharepoint.stackechange is suspended. I believe that a mod has something against me. I have nowhere to turn to or even talk to the other mods to see if this is even fair!

I don't know why I can ask questions here on Meta, but am glad that I can, to get this frustation and raise this issue! I cant believe this site is worse than real life. Who moderates the mods? I can't complain to anyone or get a fair trial!

Comment: You are complaining about it right now. So why do you think there is no way to complain?

Comment: this is the message that im getting This account is temporarily suspended for rule violations. The suspension period ends on Feb 27 at 15:28.

Comment: im not complaining, i belive a mod has unfairly susspended me.

Comment: "something against me" "frustration" "can't believe" "worse than real life" Yeah, not complaining.

Comment: Did you read the message and/or e-mail you received that came with the suspension?

Comment: your inbox/email should show the mod message.

Comment: yes i have and dont belive that its fair! I have asked for it to be peer moderated and have not got a reply back as of yet!

Comment: Do you see any comments on your questions or answers about rule violations? Did you have any correspondence from a moderator telling you that your behaviour was wrong? Did this really come "out of the blue"?

Comment: yes i have and had adherd to it until now where I got an email saying that im suspended but will rais this up as i would rather not talk about it further to turn against me

Comment: For future reference, this should have been posted on the meta site that you were suspended on.

Comment: no i cant, when your suspended you cant ask questions. On meta on stack exchange its at 1 point hence why iv asked here

Answer (score 21, accepted):

We ([the community team](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99338/who-are-the-community-managers-and-what-do-they-do) at Stack Exchange) "moderate the mods".

You can reach us via https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/contact/.

We'll be more than happy to review what happened here, but I suggest we take this to email. Please send us whatever details and context you think is necessary to describe the situation and we'll go from there.

Comment: thankyou! I will be using this, im just travling at the moment so wont be using it till later!

Comment: You "moderate the mods" but [who moderates *you*?](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a1Y73sPHKxw)

Comment: @NullUserExceptionอ_อ There are two cats on her shoulders...who do you think? Dare I say she's meowderated?...I'll leave.